# Run OrientDB in a Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, orientdb

EDIT:
Found the solution. It was a problem with minifing the code while maven build process. Run the OrientDB in a Java Applet is possible.

I have problems starting the inmemory OrientDB in a Java Applet. I use a signed Applet with OrientDB version 1.0.1. Did someone implemented the OrientDB in a Applet and can verify that this is possible or could help me with this exception?

The exception I get:

```
2012-06-20 11:22:24:734 INFO OrientDB Server v1.0.1 is starting up... [OServer]Exception in thread "thread applet-de.test.all.Applet-1" sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLFactory: Provider com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.ODefaultCommandExecutorSQLFactory not found
at sun.misc.Service.fail(Service.java:129)
at sun.misc.Service.access$000(Service.java:111)
at sun.misc.Service$LazyIterator.next(Service.java:273)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OSQLEngine.getCommandFactories(OSQLEngine.java:186)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OSQLEngine.getCommandNames(OSQLEngine.java:216)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OSQLEngine.getCommand(OSQLEngine.java:239)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:41)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:31)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.command(OStorageEmbedded.java:62)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:60)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.createClass(OSchemaShared.java:218)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.createClass(OSchemaShared.java:164)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.createClass(OSchemaShared.java:145)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.createClass(OSchemaShared.java:116)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaProxy.createClass(OSchemaProxy.java:65)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityShared.createMetadata(OSecurityShared.java:259)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityShared.create(OSecurityShared.java:202)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityProxy.create(OSecurityProxy.java:37)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadata.create(OMetadata.java:68)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.create(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:171)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.create(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:53)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.create(ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.java:54)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.loadStorages(OServer.java:451)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.loadConfiguration(OServer.java:394)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.startup(OServer.java:152)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.startup(OServer.java:143)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.startup(OServer.java:132)
at de.test.all.Applet$1.run(Applet.java:132)
at de.test.all.Applet$1.run(Applet.java:125)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at de.test.all.Applet.init(Applet.java:124)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1639)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

My Applet code to start the DB:

```
    public class Applet extends java.applet.Applet {

    OrientDbConfigurationLoader configLoader = null;
    OServer server = null;
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db = null;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new
                PrivilegedAction<OServer>() {

            public OServer run() {
                configLoader = new OrientDbConfigurationLoader("db/", "test");

                try {
                    server = OServerMain.create();
                    server.startup(configLoader.loadDefaultConfig());
                    server.activate();
                } catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) {
                    server = OServerMain.server();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong while the server should start");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("memory:temp");
                    db = db.open(OrientDbConfigurationLoader.USERNAME, OrientDbConfigurationLoader.PASSWORD);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Can't init the in-memory db.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems the usage of Java Service Registry. Look at:

```
OClassLoaderHelper.lookupProviderWithOrientClassLoader()
```

it calls:

```
ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(clazz);
```

I've just added in SVN trunk (r5909) this check:

```
 try {
          factories.add(ite.next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          OLogManager.instance().warn(null, "Cannot load OCommandExecutorSQLFactory instance from service registry", e);
        }
```

In this way a WARN is dumped but you can continue to configure your own factories if needed.